# New French Career Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

*I know this is not directly related to the French Stack Exchange, but I think that since this is the place where French experts are, the post is something that belongs here.*

Since not everybody follows the [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and that (I think) most french experts are here on this site, I would like you to see the new [French Career Stack Overflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/) site. [There is a post on the meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179610/feedback-wanted-careers-2-0-in-french) that is asking for feedback about translations and French usage on the Career site.

Here is a part of the meta post!

> We have a few native French speakers here at Stack Exchange, but we’d love your help in finding bugs, awkward translations, and anything that doesn’t feel right to our French users. There are a few specific things we need your help [...]

---

Comme tout le monde ne suit pas le [meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) et que je pense que la plupart des experts de la langue française se trouvent ici (sur le site de français), j'aimerais vous introduire au nouveau [site de carrière de Stack Overflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/fr/). Il y a présentement [un « post » sur le meta qui demande notre avis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179610/feedback-wanted-careers-2-0-in-french) sur les traductions et l'usage du français!